# Match two values in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

i am trying to replace some existing objects with a new objects in an array, i have 2 arrays `allDays` and `storedDay`,Both will be of different size allDays will 10 objects and storedDays will have 4 objects but both will have same value `day`

```
mode(){
        this.nativeStorage.getItem("modifiedData").then((data)=>{
            console.log(data)
            var allDay = this.dailyDays;
            for (var i = 0; i < allDay.length; i++) {
                var element = allDay[i];
                var storedDay = data[i];
                console.log("all Day",element.day);
                console.log("stored Day",storedDay.day);
            if (element.day === storedDay.day) {
                    console.log("we have same day", i)  
                    data=({
                        day: data.day,
                        month: data.month,
                        year: data.year,
                        quantity: data.selectedQuantity,
                        brand: data.selectedBrand,
                        price: data.price,
                    })
                    // below line will replace the whole object
                    this.dailyDays[i] = data; 
                }

            }
            console.log(data.day)
        })
    }
```

on executing the above i am getting error in stored value, could someone give example how to check two array and update the array with `storedDay`.

first line in this image is the storedDay array with 4 objects.
And allDay array will have 10 objects
[image]

Comment: What kind of value is storedDay.day? If it is an object, you cannot compare it with `===`

Comment: show us the error

Comment: are these arrays of same length?

Comment: That error is because 2 arrays are of different size, could some one suggest me how to check the both array and if any object gets added to 2nd array it should be replaced or updated  in the 1st array @Danmoreng

Answer (score 3):

you must define new variable for storing same day value:

```
mode(){
    this.nativeStorage.getItem("modifiedData").then((data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        var sameDay = null; // =======> define this variable
        var allDay = this.dailyDays;
        for (var i = 0; i < allDay.length; i++) {
            var element = allDay[i];
            var storedDay = data[i];
            console.log("all Day",element.day);
            console.log("stored Day",storedDay.day);
        if (element.day === storedDay.day) {
                console.log("we have same day", i)  
                sameDay=({ // ==========> change this
                    day: data.day,
                    month: data.month,
                    year: data.year,
                    quantity: data.selectedQuantity,
                    brand: data.selectedBrand,
                    price: data.price,
                })
                // below line will replace the whole object
                this.dailyDays[i] = sameDay; // ======> change this
            }

        }
        if(sameDay)
            console.log(sameDay.day) // =======> and change this
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i managed to find a solution this sets to my requirement

```
mode(){
        this.nativeStorage.getItem("modifiedData").then((data)=>{
            console.log(data)
             var sameDay;
            var allDay = this.dailyDays;
            for (var i = 0; i < allDay.length; i++) {
                var allDayelement = allDay[i];

                console.log("all Day",allDayelement.day);

                data.forEach(forEachElement => {
                    console.log("forEachElement",forEachElement.day);
                    if (allDayelement.day === forEachElement.day) {
                    console.log("we have same day", i)  
                    sameDay=({
                        day: forEachElement.day,
                        month: forEachElement.month,
                        year: forEachElement.year,
                        quantity: forEachElement.selectedQuantity,
                        brand: forEachElement.selectedBrand,
                        price: forEachElement.price,
                    })
                    // below line will replace the whole object
                    this.dailyDays[i] = sameDay; 
            }
                });

            }
        //  console.log(data.day)
        })
    }
```